# Find a specific time stamp in an infinite stream

Tags: linux, algorithm, sed

This is an interview question:
Say that you have an infinite amount of sorted data coming in, implement a way to find a specific time stamp.

What I can think of is to keep the data in a log file or something like that and use the sed command to find the log entry of that specific time stamp.
I do not know if what I think is correct or not.
Other solutions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems like an open-ended question. Your solution was to keep the data in a log file, but with an infinite amount of data, you would then need an impractical amount of disk space as well. The problem is probably supposed to be analyzed in the following manner.

At first glance, with an infinite stream of data coming in, it is not stated what the rate of its coming is. Assuming the rate is `r` every second and you can check only `n` timestamps every second. It is not very interesting if r <= n.

If r > n you can only check one in every `r/n` integers. Then, that means you need to maintain a buffer of size `r/n`. The fact that the input is sorted implies that you can check the ends of the buffer and see if the desired timestamp is in range. If it is, you go through your buffer and identify the required timestamp.

**Interview tip:**  It is often that these questions are open-ended in order to judge your thought processes. If it is underspecified (like it is here), you should ask for clarification.